# Java Servlet giving Error 500: Error instantiating servlet class [com.mycompany.studentdetails.StudentServlet]

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am using Java Servlet in NetBeans. Upon running the code. My BUILD is SUCCESSFULL, and my index.jsp is loading successfully. But I get a Error 505, after redirecting. Please help me out with this. This is the first time I am using Java Servlets.

Most of the code is autocomplete by NetBeans, Here I just want something to be printed in the console. But I see no reason to get a Error 505. Please help!

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Student Details</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Student Details</h1>
        <form action="details">
            <label>Enter Student ID: </label>
            <input name="id" type="text">
            <br>
            <label>Enter Student Name: </label>
            <input name="name" type="text">
            <br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>getStudentDetails</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mycompany.studentdetails.StudentServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>getStudentDetails</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/details</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

StudentServlet.java

```
public class StudentServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try ( PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet StudentServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet StudentServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
            String id = request.getParameter("id");
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            System.out.println("Working");
            System.out.println(id+name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

 
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

[image]